# AWS-EC2 100% CPU Utilization

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, amazon-cloudwatch

I am curious to know about 2 things below about the AWS-EC2 CPU utilization and CPU Credits.

What will happen if my AWS-EC2 instance CPU utilization is constantly 100% and I ran out of CPU credits?

Assume that my EC2 burstable (t-series) instance is in a shared host(which is a 8core CPU) shared by 2 VMs each 4 core. Now both the VMs are utilizing full CPU i.e. 400% each at the same time. Both the VMs are having enough CPU credits to utilize more CPU. What should be expected result here and what will be the actual result ?

Please comment if more clarification is required.

Trying to understand how the AWS CPU Credits works in the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the instance type. Some instances support busting and going over %100 usage if you have CPU Usage credits. And on that burstable types of instances CPU could be throttled if you run out of CPU credits in your bucket.

You can find a detailed explanation and how it is calculated links below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-cpu-utilization-check-throttling/